# trying to tryCatch for my function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, data-fitting

I am trying to loop this function for 1000 times and record the coefficients of the model
but sometimes when the iteration over 50 times the function stops. How can I make the function keep going and record that time fails? Thanks
I am using the tryCatch(), but I do not know how to make it work.
How can I count how many errors out of 1000 times are there?
Please help

```
e0<-1:1000
emax<-1:1000
e50<-1:1000


 for (i in 1:1000)

{
rho=0.4
#5g

pre.5mg<-rnorm(n=50,mean=-0.5,sd=0.2)
x=0.4*rho-0.5
post.5mg<-rnorm(n=50,mean=pre.5mg*rho+x,sd=sqrt((0.3*0.3*(1-rho*rho))))
#25g
pre.25mg<-rnorm(n=50,mean=-0.5,sd=0.2) 
x25=0.4*rho-1
post.25mg<-rnorm(n=50,mean=pre.25mg*rho+x25,sd=sqrt((0.3*0.3*(1-rho*rho))))  
#100g
pre.100mg<-rnorm(n=50,mean=-0.5,sd=0.2)   
x100<-0.4*rho-1.2
post.100mg<-rnorm(n=50,mean=pre.100mg*rho+x100,sd=sqrt((0.3*0.3*(1-rho*rho))))
#250g
pre.250mg<-rnorm(n=50,mean=-0.5,sd=0.2)
x250<-0.4*rho-1.4
post.250mg<-rnorm(n=50,mean=pre.250mg*rho+x250,sd=sqrt((0.3*0.3*(1-rho*rho))))   




#response
Y<-c(post.5mg,post.25mg,post.100mg,post.250mg)
#dose
dose <- c(rep(10,50),rep(30,50),rep(120,50),rep(240,50))
w<-data.frame(Y,dose)

#MLE hyperbolic EMAX
abc=nls(formula=Y~e0+((dose*emax)/(dose+ed50)),start=c(e0=1000,emax=10000,ed50=20)
  ,data=w,algorithm ="default")
bcd<-summary(abc)






e0[i]<-bcd$coef[1]
emax[i]<-bcd$coef[2]
e50[i]<-bcd$coef[3]


tryCatch(1, finally = print("failed"))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your code as follows:

```
try( {
 # put your code here
 # ...

},silent=FALSE)
```

Comment: it says Error: unexpected ',' in:

Comment: ok i got it i can run for 1000 times, but how can i get the number out of 1000  failed

Comment: Read on this link and others from google: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912